# Integrals in functions; matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if there was a way to calculate an integral without the error showing up in the results?

#### This is what I'm currently doing

```
ps = 50
rs = 5

#integral
def integrand(r,ps,rs):
    return (ps)/((r/rs)*((1+(r/rs))**2))*4*3.14159265358979323*(r**2)

integrals = []
for i in r:
     integrals.append(quad(integrand, 0 ,i,args=(ps,rs)))
```

When I do this, I get a tuple `(answer, error)` for each element of the array.

#### For example:

```
[(38.556383472098844, 4.280618467700097e-13), (237.6299245273545, 
2.6382221355020717e-12), (441.6458592544819, 4.903254016746871e-12),  
(697.2739237795256, 7.741295646507558e-12), (1018.8236494740419, 
1.131121473678711e-11), (1363.0110665120408, 1.5132462688605584e-11),
(1742.8389896517806, 1.9349399745258517e-11), (2398.270086166211, 
2.6626146689314857e-11), (3329.3070694046414, 3.696273364500337e-11)]
```

I have no interest in the error; more importantly, I need an array filled with numbers, not tuples.

Comment: cant help without knowing what the `quad` function does and its implementation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can append only the first element of the tuple returned by the integration method:

```
 integrals.append(quad(integrand, 0 , i, args=(ps, rs))[0])
```

The error will not be included in your results